# why am I getting Postgres password authentication fails error?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to learn and exercise with `postgres`.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed Postgres docker and run it with the following command:

```
sudo docker run --rm   --name pg-docker -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5433:5433 -v $HOME/amitliron/UserA/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data  postgres
```

(I'm using 5433 port, becuse when trying to use 5432 port I'm getting the following error: 
 `Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use`, I think it's not need to be problem, but writing here everying I did)

I'm trying to check the postgres docker with the following command:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d postgres
```

and entered the password: "`docker`" but I'm getting the following error:

```
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Hmm, `listen tcp 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use` might indicate another Postgres is already running? And `psql` tries to connect to it. Try to specify the port to `psql` with the `-p` flag: `psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to specify the port:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres
```